# Kubernetes pod response size limit

Tags: kubernetes, curl, calico

We have a rancher based kubernetes cluster with calico on openstack.

A spring config server (server pod here onwards) is deployed as a service.
Service is exposed on nodeport.

Another pod is deployed with curl (client pod here onwards)

Doing a curl from client pod on server pod nodeport with its node ip on which server pod is running gives proper result.

Doing curl from client pod on server nodeport with another node's ip where server pod is not running pod gives curl(56) connection reset by peer for bigger response

Doing curl from client pod on service and it's port gives results for small data but for bigger response again gives curl(56)

If both client and server pods are running on same node, response is fine.

My understanding is:

1. No issues in server pod, as able to get response on nodeport
2. No issues in client pod/curl as able to get response from nodeport
3. Service and pod linkage is fine as it works well with small response size

When I say bigger response, I mean just 1 kb+

Answer (score 0):

It will give an error when there is no reply from the server.

Ex:

```
$ curl http://youtube.com:443
Curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Please recheck your proxy, firewall settings.

Comment: There is no proxy or firewalls. And It is pod to pod communication